# Rails: Updating Nested attributes - undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

**Edit:** Added the update action, and on what line the error occurs

Model:

```
class Match < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_and_belongs_to_many :teams
  has_many :match_teams
  has_many :teams, :through => :match_teams
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :match_teams, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

Controller:

```
  def new
    @match = Match.new
    @match_teams = 2.times do
      @match.match_teams.build
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @match }
    end
  end

  def update
    @match = Match.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @match.update_attributes(params[:match])
        format.html { redirect_to @match, notice: 'Match was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @match.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Nested model:

```
class MatchTeam < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :match
  belongs_to :team
end
```

Association:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :matches
end
```

View:

```
<%= form_for(@match) do |f| %>

  <%= f.fields_for :match_teams, @match_teams do |builder| %>
    <%= builder.collection_select :team_id, Team.all, :id, :name, :include_blank => true %>
  <% end %>

  <% unless @match.new_record? %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :winning_team_id %><br />
      <%= f.collection_select :winning_team_id, @match.teams, :id, :representation %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Params:

```
Processing by MatchesController#update as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"Ô£ô", "authenticity_token"=>"QIJChzkYOPZ1hxbzTZS8H3AXc7i
BzkKv3Z5daRmlOsQ=", "match"=>{"match_teams_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"team_id"=>"1", "
id"=>""}, "1"=>{"team_id"=>"3", "id"=>""}}, "winning_team_id"=>"3"}, "commit"=>"
Update Match", "id"=>"2"}
```

Creating a new match with 2 teams work fine, the edit view also shows the correct values, but the update action gives me this error.

```
undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass
app/controllers/matches_controller.rb:65:in `block in update'

line 65: if @match.update_attributes(params[:match])
```

Comment: You'd want to show your code for the update action.

Comment: Where does `undefined method 'to_sym' for nil:NilClass` come from? (file + line no)

Comment: Sorry guys, edited the post with the missing info.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've figured it out. I read that a join table like MatchTeams doesn't need an ID. I'm guessing this is true when not doing any nested forms. I redid my migration removing the exclusion of the id column, and now everything works fine. Don't we all love this stupid errors? :)

Comment: Same error for me, thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I needed to explicitly set the primary key on the **model** ie:  `self.primary_key = 'something_else'` fixed it right up ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the offending `to_sym` in your code, just know that the thing it's attached to has not been defined properly. If this is a variable such as `@var.to_sym`, you most likely:

1. Haven't set `@var` at all
2. Set it but it's returning `nil` because there are no matches (e.g. `@var = @project.companies.first` but `@project` has no companies tied to it).
3. You are missing a relevant bit of data in your `params`. If your to_sym is relying on data submitted through the form, it won't work if the user leaves out the bit of data you're assuming. In this case, you should test first to see if the data was entered before running `.to_sym` on it.